# Getting only one '\' character when joining a list

Tags: python, join

I want to have a string with the`'\w'`character after each letter.

For example:

```
my_string = 'asdfg'
```

What I want:

```
my_string = 'a\ws\wd\wd\wf\wg\w'
```

Now, how I approached this is first storing each letter into a list:

```
list=[]
for i in my_string:
    list.append(i)
```

And then joining it with a `\w` character in between to form my new string. However, I ran into some problems.

```
'\w'.join(list)
```

I'm getting a double backslash character instead of one:

```
'q\\ww\\we\\wr\\wt\\wy\\wu\\wy\\wt\\wr\\we\\ws\\wd\\wf\\wt\\wy\\wu\\wi\\wo\\wk\\wn\\wn'
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help in fixing this. Thanks.

Comment: Why? Nothing is broken.

Comment: Escape characters. Look  them up

Comment: `'\w'.join(list(my_string))` is more correct, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` is not a character. You might be thinking of another escape character, but `'\w'` simply evaluates to `'\\w'`, since `\w` just doesn't exist.

Oh, you might also want to replace your for loop with simply `list(my_string)` or `tuple(my_string)` - or even the entire thing with `'[whatever character you actually wanted]'.join(my_string)` - it's simpler and does the same thing. To get your expected result, you'll also need to add the character to the end of the string, as in `'[x]'.join(my_string) + '[x]'`. As it stands now, you won't get the character after the very last letter.

Comment: you don't even need to do `list(my_string)`. Simple `'\w'.join(my_string)` will work.

Comment: @M.Klugerford Ah, true. Should've thought a step further.